# Integral using long division

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the integral

$$\int\frac{x^2+1}{6x-9x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

$$\rightarrow \left(-9x^2+6x\right):\left(1+x^2\right)\ $$
$$+9x^2+0x+9$$
$$\rightarrow6x+9$$

Im tumped here, because I dont know how to continue with the longdivision to get rid of the 'x'-part. It's not like I can multiply $(1+x^2)$ with a square root, or can I (?), if so, how?

Comment: Do you know how to do polynomial long division? You will get terms such as $1/x$, but you can still follow the same process even if the numerator is smaller than the denominator.

Comment: I did it in high school, and I this is as far as I got by just remembering (and some time on google ofc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{x^2+1}{6x-9x^2}=-\frac{x^2+1}{9x^2-6x}=-\frac19\frac{9x^2+9}{9x^2-6x}=-\frac19\left(1+\frac{9+6x}{9x^2-6x}\right)$$
$$=-\frac19-\frac19\frac{3+2x}{3x^2-2x}=-\frac19-\frac{(3+2x)}{9x(3x-2)}$$
can you finish it from here?

Comment: I am supposed to end up with -(1/9) + ( (2/3)x + 1 )/( 6x - 9x^2 ), but it is the long division part (the part that my book has skipped because it's trivial) I am struggling with, and I need to know the 'trivial' parts to fully understand

Comment: @Mampenda have you heard of partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: Yes, that's the subject im working with now. And I know what to do once I have performed the long division, but I struggle with the actual long division.

Comment: it is solving simultaneous equations effectively, assume that $$\frac{3+2x}{9x(3x-2)}=\frac{a}{9x}+\frac{b}{3x-2}$$